# pausing node-osmosis between scrapes

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am reading the links from csv and using it to scrape. I want the node-osmosis to wait between the scrapes may be after scraping 10 sites. I tried using sleep but it seems to sleep at the wrong time while a the next site is being scraped causing it to fail.

```
const osmosis = require('osmosis');
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = fs.createReadStream("data.csv");
const csv = require('fast-csv');

let ii = 0;

const scrapeData = (row) => {

  osmosis
    .get(row[0])
    .set({
      'data': '#data',
    })
    .data(function (listing) {
        fs.appendFileSync('out2.ssv',listing.data);

       if(ii%10 == 0 && ii!==0){
           console.log('ss',ii);
          sleep.sleep(1000);
     }


      }
    })
}

let csvStream = csv()
  .on("data", function (data) {
      scrapeData(data)
      ii++;
  });

  stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

how do I proceed with this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: may be you should try moving if block above readFileSync...

Comment: I am not using readFileSync

Comment: I am just using blocking write for appending contents

Comment: i mean, moving if block above appendFileSync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that node is asynchronous. Your query is going to run everything in parallel and sleep after it has done. Perhaps what you want to do is use setInterval or setTimeout. Something like this?

```
 var shouldPauseForTenSeconds = false
var listOfDataItems = []
var numberOfProcessedItems = 0

function scrapeData (row) {
    if(shouldPauseForTenSeconds) {
        shouldPauseForTenSeconds = false;
        setTimeout(scrapeData.bind(null,row), 10000);
    }
    listOfDataItems.push(row)
    numberOfProcessedItems++;
    if(numberOfProcessedItems % 10 == 0 && numberOfProcessedItems > 0) {
        numberOfProcessedItems = 0;
        shouldPauseForTenSeconds = true;
    }

    osmosis
        .get(row[0])
        .set({
            'data': '#data',
        })
        .data(function (listing) {
            fs.appendFileSync('out2.ssv',listing.data);
        })
}

let csvStream = csv()
.on("data", function (data) {
    scrapeData(data)
    ii++;
});

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```